# Finding lowest elevation point over borders of Polygon

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am new to QGIS and I have a polygon shapefile and a raster DEM file. I want to find the lowest elevation point over boundaries of each polygon in QGIS.

Can anyone please tell me the way to do this?

I also want to know the list polygons this points is part of (as it is boundary point). I want longitude an latitude of lowest elevation point over boundary of each polygon and as this point lies on shared boundary hence I need list of other polygons on which this point lies.

I need this to make a stream flow sequence for such drainage points and need to use this for other computation after having such dependencies of water stream flow among polygons

As in image encircled red point lowest elevation point for polygon numbed 25 and blue encircled point is for polygon no 18. Also Red encircled point lies in boundaries of polygon 5,7,25,18. I want similar lowest elevation points (Long. and Lat.) for each polygon and polygon list for each such point.

[image: Image for explanation]